# url parameter unsets cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've hit a problem and cannot fathom an answer. For some reason, when I redirect the user back to the page with the url parameter of **?saved=true** it seems to unset the cookie and thus log the user out.

At the top of every page I have this PHP:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE["LoggedIn"])) {
    echo "There is a cookie set ";
    $isLoggedIn = true; 
} else {
 // perform check for user against db and then set session and cookie
}
```

The page that is redirecting it, is using the header location:

```
if($sql) {
    header("Location: http://site.co.uk/".$page.".php?saved=true");
}
```

**Edit** : : 
Here is the code where the cookies is set, if there are rows returned, i.e there is a matching username and password:

```
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $loggedInUser =  $row['username'];
    }
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username']=md5($loggedInUser);

    $value = $_SESSION['username'];

    setcookie("LoggedIn",$value);
}
```

The setting of the cookie is fine, its the fact it keeps getting deleted when the redirect page happens. argh!

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what does `$sql` have ?

Comment: $sql is just the INSERT command for the database to save the data

Comment: post the code where cookies is set.

Comment: I hope it doesn’t suffice to provide the MD5 hash of an existing user’s name in a cookie to impersonate him/her.

Comment: @MarkP Well, I meant I hope that providing the cookie `LoggedIn=21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3` doesn’t make me the `admin` user without proper authentication.

Comment: Are you staying on the same domain (and protocol) with your redirect?

Comment: @Gumbo at present yes, oh dear :(

Comment: @MarkP Why do you use the cookie anyway? I mean, you already have a session that I assume is only set after successful authentication.

Comment: @Gumbo - I originally didnt have a cookie set and it is still doing the same thing with the session. I just added that in to see whether a cookie would fix the problem